# Can not install elementary OS on DELL D631

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install elementary OS on my Dell Latitude D631 but failed.

In the beginning of installation I have some very fast warnings and after only letter E in circle. Laptop is stopping in this position and nothing happens except letter E on screen.

I have Dell Latitude D631 with AMD Turion 64 X2 TL-60 2GHz and SSD disk.
elementary OS elementaryos-stable-0.3.1-amd64

Also I could not find my DELL Latitude D631 at Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware list.

Does it mean I have to be with Windows all the time on this laptop?

Thank you!

Comment: I see no immediate reason why your machine would not run, and have been advised that you can press `Esc` and see what is going on behind the boot screen (the one with the circled e). Maybe that will provide us with some info to work with. That said, 0.3.1 has been replaced, 0.3.2 was released a few days ago. Perhaps, before struggling with this, try the most recent version first.

Comment: Hello Lewis! Thanks for your reply! I tried to install **0.3.2** version but the result is the same. I can add a couple of more details to it: a) I catched part of notice in the beginning of installation- it says something like **"MTR CPU0 SYSCFG error..."**; b) letter E on screen was blinking few times before laptop became dead. At the same time I could run Ububtu in test mode at least , booting from USB stick in both cases.

Comment: Hey @Mixa_ru, it appears that perhaps your motherboard doesn't support MTRR (two Rs), which means it doesn't clear your memory on shutdown. You should probably try with `nomtrr` (I have no idea how to do that) or consider a newer machine. While elementary is lightweight, lack of support for modern options can cause all kinds of odd issues.

Comment: Lewis hello again! Yes, that's right-  my laptop is quite old and that's the reason I'd like to use Elementary OS to keep notebook with me and be productive. Anyway thanks for your attempt to help and if you will get to know how to make installation please come back with ideas.  With best wishes!

Comment: Your PC is quite old.But elementary works for me on a Sony VAIO VGN-NR120E and so does Windows 10 Insider

Answer (score 1):

Press any key before the elementary logo when booting the live USB.You should see some thing with options.Then press F6 and after that ESC .Type SPACE (press space key) + `nomtrr` and press enter.If it does not work add a photo of the boot command line in the comments

Comment: thanks for your reply! It was asked long time ago but anyway may be it will help someone else.

Comment: @Mixa_ru Does it work.If it does mark as answer (and upvote if you like)

Comment: I upwoted but I can not check it because I asked this long time ago and time passed I switched to another laptop without elementary. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @Mixa_ru What happened to the laptop

Comment: it needs mechanical repair now (old laptop)

Comment: @Mixa_ru Why would it need repair.It was working correctly

Comment: @Suici_Doga, most issues with dust inside and overheating and keyboards, also screen feels itself bad. These issues of course do not connected with elementary OS but they interfere me to continue to work with this laptop.

Comment: @Mixa_ru The VAIO was also full of dust.Normal with old computers